# Как сократить горизонтальное расстояние между элементами GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

По задумке, мой `GridView` - сетка `8х8` сплошных элементов (поле, состоящие из картинок). При добавлении `ImageView` (простые shape drawable) через адаптер , между колонками образуется пробел и я не понимаю, как от него избавится.

С вертикальными пробелами все норм.

**Код адаптера:**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView img;
    if (convertView == null) {
        img = new ImageView(myCtx);
        img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    } else {
        img = (ImageView)convertView;
    }
    Random random = new Random();
    int rand = random.nextInt(5);
    img.setImageResource(images[rand]);
    return img;
}
```

**XML GridView:**

```
<GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/field"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:numColumns="8"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp" />
```

Comment: убрать атрибуты horizontalSpacing и verticalSpacing?

Comment: @georgehardcore, скорее выставить их значение в 0. В теме приложения они могут быто определены, и если их убрать, то они примут значение поумолчанию для темы

Comment: не помогло... :-/

Comment: А если так, gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);

Comment: вообще изображения никакого не видно (как и когда stretch none выставляется в XML). Попробовал использовать Gridlayout, но там другая проблема - поиск позиции элемента (ячейки) и ее удаление (при необходимости) без смещения всех остальных элементов. Может вторую проблему проще решить? )

Comment: Можно использовать RecyclerView с GridLayoutManager
Пример: http://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/

Comment: Спасибо! Буду разбираться)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте GridLayout из библиотеки совместимости `compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.0'` с параметрами

```
app:columnCount="8"
app:rowCount="8"
```

Там можно выставить параметры для каждого View и они расположатся как надо.

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_columnWeight="1"
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
```

Comment: похоже то, что надо

Comment: Как айтем отрисован млжет там заданы отсьупы у наружнего контейнера , если вы поняли о чем я